# Converting an uint8_t[] to an IP address string

Tags: c, ip-address

I am currently learning C. My ecosystem consists of an Espressif ESP-32 micro controller and Eclipse CDT IDE.

I am trying to convert an `uint8_t[]` to a human readable `IPv4 address string`. I came up with the following code so far:

```
void app_main() {
    uint8_t[] ip = {192, 168, 0, 99};
    dump_ip(ip);
}

void dump_ip(const uint8_t *in) {
    // ip addresses consist of three dots + terminator '\0'
    int size = 4;
    // count amount of chars needed for specific ip address
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if(in[i]==0) {
            size ++;
        } else {
            size += ((int)log10(in[i]))+1;
        }
    }
    // allocate memory on heap for an ip address of length 'size'
    char *ip_str = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));
    // copy ip address parts to char array
    int pos = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if(in[i]==0) {
            ip_str[pos] = '0';
            pos++;
        } else {
            char b[4];
            itoa(in[i], b, 10);
            for(int j=0; j<3; j++) {
                if(b[j]!='0') {
                    ip_str[pos] = b[j];
                    pos++;
                }
            }
        }
        // add dot between ip address parts
        if(i<3) {
            ip_str[pos] = '.';
            pos++;
        }
    }
    // add terminator at end of string
    ip_str[pos] = '\0';
    // print to uart interface
    uart_send(ip_str);
    // release allocated heap memory
    free(ip_str);
}
```

I get the following results when testing with different IP arrays:

```
uint8_t[] ip = {192, 168, 0, 99};   =>   "192.168.0.99"   => OK
uint8_t[] ip = {192, 168, 1, 99};   =>   "192.168.1"      => FAILED
uint8_t[] ip = {192, 168, 10, 99};  =>   "192.168.1"      => FAILED
uint8_t[] ip = {10, 10, 10, 10};    =>   "1"              => FAILED
// etc. etc. etc.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there some more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: how about using inet_ntoa

Comment: why not reserve a fixed size buffer rather than all teh complicated logic. The longest a ipv4 address can be is 16 (999.999.999.999\0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `snprintf` it.

```
void app_main() {
    uint8_t ip[] = {192, 168, 0, 99};
    char buf[3 * 4 + 3 * 1 + 1];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
    uart_send(buf);
}
```

`uint8_t[] ip` is not valid C, the `[]` comes after the variable name.

1. The `sprintf` and `snprintf` will print the formatted string into the memory pointed to by the first arg.
2. The `snprintf` takes additional maximum size argument as the second arg.
3. The `uint8_t` variables are auto-casted to `int` when passing in variable arguments list - thus you can print them using `%d` printf modifier.
4. Then you have human readable, null terminated string.

Comment: great, one line :-) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is simply to use `snprintf` as suggested by Kamil Cuk.

However if you're still wondering why your code didn't work, the answer is on this line:

```
if(b[j]!='0') {
```

you are only copying characters that aren't zero, which includes null chars. So when a segment of the IP contains less than 3 characters you will be copying a null into the string. The fix is very simple:

```
if(b[j]!='\0') {
```

which makes me think it may well have just been a typo!

Comment: thanks for your explanation!